# What does the と at the end, following a complete sentence and comma mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, particle-と, colloquial-language

What is purpose of the と at the end of this sentence? And why is there a comma before it?

> 少ししたらぽっかり目が覚めちゃって、気付いたら佳織ちゃんとひとつベッドの上だった、と

For context this was the *previous* sentence.

> 忍び込んだはいいけど、一気に眠気でばたんきゅーしちゃって

And this is the *next* sentence.

> たぶん無意識に、こういう状況を予測してたんだね

I'm aware that [somebody has asked a question with a sentence that has seemingly the same ending structure](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62152/ending-sentences-with-%E3%81%A8) but I don't think this is the case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially a guess, but it is essentially the same as the one you linked.

The と is quotative, bracketing the preceding sentence.

From what you put, possibly the speaker is saying **「**忍び込んだはいいけど、一気に眠気でばたんきゅーしちゃって少ししたらぽっかり目が覚めちゃって、気付いたら佳織ちゃんとひとつベッドの上だった**」という**状況をたぶん無意識に予測してたんだね.

Since the quoted part is long, the spearker first describes the situation and then says 'you expected unconsciously this kind of situation'.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!